# Redirect multiple URLs to multiple alternative URLs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension which will redirect certain sites to others.

Currently, I'm using a piece of code kindly written by a user here and it works like a charm. The only thing, it redirects one site only.
How can I get it to have a list of sites redirected to others I can specify?

Here's the current code of the background.js:

```
var host = "http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://piratebay.se/*",
            "*://www.piratebay.se/*"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```